# iOS: How can we find that specific framework used for which third party library

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, ads

My app is rejected due to [IDFA] included.

On the other hand app does not support any ads.

How can we check if `AdSupport.framework` is included for which particular library? Is there any way?

Thanks

Comment: Delete the framework from the project and compile the project. Check which library throws the error.

Comment: I have done. But there is no error, only I can see "Build failed" and some warnings. Nothing else @Apurv

Comment: Check all the warnings. At the end of all the warnings there must be an error.

Comment: Yeah I know about the trick errors always at the end bit really no error found and warnings also common warnings. @Apurv

Comment: which Ads network SDK you are using ?

Comment: compile it with command line and check.